# How can I automate this kind of Blender 2D animations?

Tags: python, animation, video-sequence-editor, video

I've started using blender VSE only for now, as my essential tooling for creating this kind of free educational resources for children:
[My Video example](https://youtu.be/3dLv5deySrA)

And I'm asking you about a way to automate this kind of Blender VSE projects, because I'm new to the animation world, and from my little experience, it is very time consuming.

Comment: Which part of the video are you trying to replicate? Any user interaction will require more than just a video

Comment: It is unclear what part of the process you need help with. Please read: [What is the problem with posting an image (or link) and asking “How do I do this?”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I still could not find a way to automate the process of creating this kind of animations.

As an example, i've reached the Alphabet letter P and Pumpkin Coloring Page for kids, here: https://youtu.be/UHTRP29TCHQ

As you can see, it is all made by hand no automation. I've read about using the API scripting capabilities provided with blender and python.

And i'm not sure how to deal with this issue. Breaking the problem apart, i need to automate these 3 tasks using python and Blender API:

1- How to script copying a strip

Answer (score 1):

Blender can do many of the effects seen in this video, but the drawing and colouring in effect is  screen capture.
Having said that you can sort of fake it by capturing a drawn frame, using Grease Pencil in the VSE preview window. Grab it by rendering with the OpenGL render button. Thats the little camera button highlighted in yellow.

[image: Grab a grease pencil frame]

You can re-import this frame and wipe it on over the clean frame. Remember to turn off the Grease Pencil layer.

[image: wipe on Grease Pencil]

Comment: Please explain how to draw into the VSE Image Preview window - despite enabling Grease Pencil Layers there, the Tool Shelf with the Grease Pencil Draw command is not accessible there. When I click into the window, I just get pixel information shown at the bottom. Am I missing a setting? (my goal is to annotate a video I'm editing - no 3D rendering or Node compositing going on so far)

Comment: What could work is drawing on the Render Result, as that Grease Pencil Layer than is visible in the VSE Image Preview. However, with Stroke Placement set to View it is probably useless, as even setting Zoom 1:1 in both views results in misalignment of the strokes between views. Setting it to Cursor results in a tiny point in Image Preview, that then is even less visible in Render Result. Manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/grease_pencil/drawing/introduction.html Nothing to see of the GP layer in 3D View, either.